# How to force xmlspy code to write out qualified namespaces on elements?

Tags: java, xml, xmlspy, altova

I have used XmlSpy 2013 to generate program code in Java from a schema.  My application basically reads in xml from a file, modifies the xml, and writes it back out to the file.  The generated code provides classes and functions to do the load:

```
sampleSchema2 doc = sampleSchema2.loadFromFile(filePath);
// Load the file into Java objects...
```

and to write the file back out:

```
sampleSchema2 sampleDoc = sampleSchema2.createDocument();
// Populate the doc from the modified Java objects...
sampleDoc.saveToFile(path, true);
```

The schema I used to generate the code has the following attributes:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:bfrs="http://www.example.com/schema/bfrs" xmlns:cnc="http://www.example.com/schema/cnc" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/schema/cnc" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2006/05/30" xml:lang="en">
```

The xml files I read in use qualified namespaces for the elements like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cnc:cnc versionNumber="v.2.2.1" versionDate="2012-04-03" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schema/cnc exampleSchema.xsd" xmlns:cnc="http://www.example.com/schema/cnc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <cnc:Revisions>
        <cnc:Revision>S003</cnc:Revision>
    </cnc:Revisions>
```

...

But after I write the file out again using saveToFile() as above, all of the qualified namespaces are removed from the elements like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cnc versionNumber="v.2.2.1" versionDate="2012-04-03" xmlns:cnc="http://www.example.com/schema/cnc">
    <Revisions>
        <Revision>S003</Revision>
    </Revisions>
```

...

Does anyone know how I can get xmlspy to qualify the namespaces on the documents so they look like how I read them in?  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this is currently impossible using Altova generated code per my response from Altova technical support:

> Thanks for contacting us.
>
> I'm afraid that it's currently not presently possible to control the
>   namespace prefix in the generated code.
>
> I'll forward your message on to our development team for future
>   consideration.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Mxxxxxxxx Kxxxxx
>   Support Engineer
>   Altova GmbH